# Postfix: rewriting the recipient domain on relayed mail

Tags: postfix, sympa

I have a mail relay (`mx2.mycorp.com`)which accepts mail for `somelist@lists.mycorp.com`. These posts are forwarded to a Sympa mailing list server which accepts postings for the `mycorp.com` domain.

This has been working for quite some time on an older version of Sympa and Ubuntu 14.04 but the problem is both stacks have needed upgrades and deprecation in both pieces of software have broken much of the setup.

I'm starting over with Ubuntu 18.04 but can't quite figure out how to get postfix transports for `lists.mycorp.com` working for relaying to the Sympa server in a way that sympa will accept the posting for the mailing list. Right now the sympa server is simply relaying the posting out to the egress mail server because it's not configured to accept mail for 'lists.mycorp.com`(only`mycorp.com`). This was configured for vanity reasons; the stakeholders in the project don't want a subdomain for their mailing lists.

Is there a way to get postfix to rewrite the destination domain *after* it's figured out where it needs to relay the message?

Contents of `postconf -n` and `postconf -M`:

```
# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases,hash:/etc/mail/sympa/aliases
alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-sympa-lists-with-exclusions.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-sympa-owners.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-sympa-request.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-sympa-u
nsubscribe.cf,hash:/etc/mail/sympa/aliases,hash:/etc/aliases
biff = no
default_privs = sympa
home_mailbox = .maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps =
mailbox_size_limit = 60000000
mailbox_transport = smtp:[mx1.mycorp.com]:2525
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain, lists.mycorp.com, lists.test.mycorp.com
mydomain = mycorp.com
myhostname = lists.mycorp.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.140.136.0/23
myorigin = $mydomain
readme_directory = no
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/myrecipientmap
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydestination, lists.mycorp.com
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 5
smtp_host_lookup = native,dns
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
sympa_destination_recipient_limit = 1
sympabounce_destination_recipient_limit = 1
transport_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/transport_regexp
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

# postconf -M
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -v
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
sympa      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=R user=sympa argv=/usr/lib/sympa/bin/queue ${recipient}
sympabounce unix -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=R user=sympa argv=/usr/lib/sympa/bin/bouncequeue ${recipient}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense. Attached.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if the article I wrote is related to this problem, yet I had a similar problem on upgrading tu ubuntu 22.04 and replacing mailman2 and I had to document the solution so [here](https://ajoliveira.com/ajoliveira/uk/software/sympa_postfix.php) it is, with links to other solutions: